# How can I connect my public SO account with my SO for teams of my company?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Our company just opted in for SO for teams.

I would like to connect my personal account with that account, just like the SE network, or something similar.

Is that possible?

I couldn't find that answer on Google.

Comment: What happens when you try to add the account in your [My Logins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/me) page?

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic here (see tag description). The connection between your SO/SE accounts and your Teams account now only exists in Teams. For example, they used to allow you to see your Teams notifications in your SO/SE inbox but that's now gone.

Comment: @ThomA I added the team's account to the main one, but when entering https://stackoverflowteams.com/ it doesn't show any link whatsoever

Comment: @Laurel the tag explicitly reads "except questions about the link to the public site"

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't show any link? You add the account here on [so], not teams.

Comment: @ThomA On stackoverflow, I added the work account as a login. Nothing on either site is aware of the other. If you meant to do some other process, please post as an answer so that I can follow along.

Comment: So you haven't (yet) tried to add the login on your [My Logins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current) page using the [Add more logins…](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent) feature?

Comment: @ThomA I added the work email to my logins. On stackoverflowforteams nothing indicates my main account, and on the main account nothing indicates the teams account.